# Can't Store NGinx Version to Variable

Tags: nginx, bash, scripting, centos7

This seems like a stupid question, but I can't seem to store the `nginx -v` output to a variable or even write it to a file in bash.  `php --version` and `mysql --version` seem to work fine, but Nginx won't save.  Is there anyway to do this.  I am trying:

```
NGINX_VERSION=$(nginx -v)
nginx -v > /home/user/nginxversion.txt
```

PHP works fine in the same manner, but nginx won't save.

```
PHP_VERSION=$(php --version)
php -v > /home/user/phpversion.txt
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nginx` writes its version info to `stderr` not `stdout` so to capture it you'll need to redirect it like

```
nginx_version=$(nginx -v 2>&1)
```

or

```
nginx -v 2> /home/user/nginxversion.txt
```

Also, note that you should not use all upper case for your variable names, lest you collide with environment variables or similar.